# WCF Calls cause "A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall" error

Tags: wcf, sockets, timeout

In our production environment, we have a WCF serivce that is very frequently called.
We noticed that sometimes, calls to this service (only this one) fail on timeout for a period of time, after everything falls into place and the service responds correctly again.

I used Dynatrace to try to understand what's happening, I noticed that for the calls resulting on a timeout, the method of the service is never called ! And at the same time the server throw this error

> A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to
>   WSACancelBlockingCall

and the client throws a Timeout Exception.

I want to understand the cause of this errors. Is the server error caused by the client's TimeoutException (when the client close its connection) ? Otherwise why do the server throw this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach a screenshot of that PurePath?
The TimeoutException is simply thrown by the caller of a service when the called web services doesnt return within the default timeout - typically something like 60s. And - once the client aborts its network connection it will cause the exception in the server who has accepted that connection.
There can be multiple reasons for this slow behavior, e.g: you are maxing out the number of connections you have in your client - or the server implementation is overloaded and cant handle incoming requests. Definitely look at the number of worker threads/connections configured on both sides

If you want specific help on dynatrace freel free to send over the PurePaths - check out http://bit.ly/sharepurepath

hope this helps